# Python IndexError: list index out of range upon entering AWS instance id

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm getting an error now in my program that says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\aws_ec2_terminate_instances.py", line 17, in <module>
    )['Reservations'][0]['Instances'][0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The problem happens as soon as I feed it the info it's asking for:

```
Enter instance IDs separated by commas: i-024b3382f94bce588
```

Here's my program:

```
import boto3
import collections
from collections import defaultdict
import time
import datetime
from datetime import datetime

ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
instance_id_list = input("Enter instance IDs separated by commas: ")
instance_ids = instance_id_list.split(",")
for instance_id in instance_ids:
    instance = ec2.describe_instances(
        InstanceIds=[instance_id]
        )['Reservations'][0]['Instances'][0]
    ec2info = defaultdict()
    ec2info[instance['InstanceId']] = {
        'Instance ID': instance['InstanceId'],
        'Type': instance['InstanceType'],
        'State': instance['State']['Name'],
        'Private IP': instance['PrivateIpAddress'],
    }

    # Add instance info to a dictionary
    attributes = ['Name', 'Instance ID', 'Type',
              'State', 'Private IP', launch_time_friendly ]
    for instance_id, instance in ec2info.items():
        for key in attributes:
            print("{0}: {1}".format(key, instance[key]))
    time.sleep(5)
    ec2.modify_instance_attribute(InstanceId=instance_id, DisableApiTermination={'Value':False})
    ec2.terminate_instances(InstanceIds=[instance_id], DryRun=False)
    print("------")
```

How do I correct this?

Comment: Please print the content of `ec2.describe_instances(
        InstanceIds=[instance_id]
        )['Reservations']` and tell us what it is.

Comment: If there are no reservations then `['Reservation'][0]` will be out of range. If there are no instances in the reservation, `['Instances'][0]` will be out of range.

Comment: I added these lines and this is what I got:

 instance_info = ec2.describe_instances( InstanceIds=[instance_id] )['Reservations']
    print("Instance Info = ", instance_info)

Comment: Instance Info =  []

Comment: So it's like I said above, there are no reservations. You can't index an empty list.